# How to change svn commit message

Tags: svn, scripting, commit-message

I wrote a script which can auto commit in every 10 minutes. But it's commit message always same ("Code saved"). But i want to change some of them which are milestone.

This is my auto commit script:

```
cd c:\inetpub\wwwroot\siteCodes
svn commit -m "Code Saved"
```

How can i write a script which can give me a chance to write revision number and new commit message.

Comment: If you are auto-committing every 10 minute how are you going to specify a commit message? Manually every 10 minutes? Or do a diff and somehow generate a commit message from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your actual question (at personal risk), svn requires explicit permission to be set in a hook script before it will allow the log message to be changed.  I never have a repository long before I need this.  Here's a batch file you can use.  Put it in the repository's "hooks" folder and call it pre-revprop-change.bat

http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-03/0107.shtml

Or a little more readable version,

http://ayria.livejournal.com/33438.html

Of course, I agree with everyone else that your setup is very sub-optimal.  But you'll inevitably need to change the log message for a *good* reason sooner or later. :)

Comment: +1 for taking a risk and showing how to do it. I also +1 OrbMan's statement that this is a bad idea.

Comment: I think this will help to me. Thank you. In my opinion this is not bad idea because svn server doesn't work for only one thing for my projects. I am lonely programmer and nobody confused with these "auto backup" messages. I feel very good even if i lose my computer because every line of code is in the same place with my real revisions. This is the most important thing for me ;) THANK YOU HARPO because of you answered my question and shared your idea.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bad approach, you should not auto-commit. Source control should not be treated like a backup system.

Instead, commit when a logical chunk of work is completed. Always try to commit code in a  state that will build properly. And then, you have the opportunity to type whatever commit message you want.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but i am working on virtual machine and i lost my all codes because of vmdk didn't work. And there might be a common usage svn servers. But for me, this is not bad way to use svn. Thus, i donot worry to loose my virtual machine because it is automatically commiting.

Comment: @uzay95: if you are having problems with your virtual machine, fix those. Don't use SVN as a bandaid.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you think SVN server is very upset because i use it that way?

Comment: SVN isn't intended to be used this way, in a real environment with many programmers committing work in you certainly would not want to do this. There are several reasons for not auto-committing, a few of them are: harder to track changes and logs are flooded with trivial changes. If you were the only person then I suppose it isn't as bad but I'm certain there are other solutions that's geared toward your specific problem.